# Dell Inspiron 580 erratic CPU fan speed after version advancement

Tags: 14.04, dell, cpu, fan, sensors

As per title i'm experiencing a nerve wracking issue: as soon as i did the LTS advancement from 14.04 to 16.04 my cpu fan started behaving erraticly, spiking in speed every few seconds for approx one second, then slowing down, then spiking up again and so on.
I am not very experienced with Ubuntu, and i've tried lm sensors and pwmconfig but to no avail. Using them makes the Cpu fan go 100%, but even then i can hear it going faster then slower. 
i also have win 7 installed and the issue is not present there.
i tried reinstalling (i'm back on 14.04 now) but even on the live USB key the issue is already there. I have no idea how to solve it, i hope someone can help me.